# Ubuntu not starting after clicking restart button as the installation process completes

Tags: boot, dual-boot, restart

I'm using an Acer Nitro AN515-52 laptop. I installed Ubuntu Studio 18.04 alongside Windows 10. Secure boot already disabled. After the installation finished, I clicked on restart button. The screen got stuck. After some time, the following boot messages appeared.

[image]

Comment: Did you set "trust" on the grubx64.efi boot file?  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/751664/ubuntu-15-10-is-not-in-boot-manager/751894#751894

Answer (score 0):

It started after I added [nomodeset](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077486/1077489#1077489) at the start.